# .NET Interop - Passing COM interface from managed code to native

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop, marshalling, com-interop

Say I have COM interface `IFoo` defined in some type-library *Foo.tlb*.

I also have unmanaged DLL written in C++ that exports the following function (expects as input COM object that implements `IFoo`):

```
#import "Foo.tlb"

__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(Foo::IFoo* p)
{
    ...
}
```

Now I have managed assembly written in C++/CLI having `IFoo^` somewhere in the code. I add project reference to the above DLL and want to call `MyFunc()`.

What would be the correct syntax for the following code? How can I specify the CLR to perform marshalling from `IFoo^` to `IFoo*`? (I want it to create COM Callable Wrapper automatically)

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(Foo::IFoo* p);

void CallDLL(Foo::IFoo^ f)
{
    MyFunc(f);
}
```

***Workaround:***

If I change the code to pass the parameter as `void *` and create the CCW manually - it works:

Unmanaged (C++):

```
#import "Foo.tlb"

__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(void* p)
{
    Foo::IFoo *pFoo = (Foo::IFoo *)p;
    ...
}
```

Managed (C++/CLI):

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(void *p);

void CallDLL(Foo::IFoo^ f)
{
    IntPtr p;
    try
    {
        p = Marshal::GetComInterfaceForObject(f, Foo::IFoo::typeid);
        MyFunc((void *)p);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal::Release(p);
    }
}
```

But how can I do it strongly-typed?

Comment: Well, you already know it.  The basic hangup is that the Foo::IFoo identifier is ambiguous.  In the native code it is the unmanaged COM interface that was #imported, in the C++/CLI code it is the managed interface that was synthesized from the project reference.  You can disambiguate by either using the rename_namespace attribute in the #import directive or by using the /namespace option for Tlbimp.exe.  The former can be done in code so probably the one you prefer.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks! I missed this point. But I still fail to figure out instructing the CLR to automatically create the CCW. I got this code: `#import "Foo.tlb" rename_namespace("FooUM")` so that I have managed class implementing `Foo::IFoo^` and DLL function with `FooUM::IFoo*` param. I can use `GetComInterfaceForObject` to create CCW and manually cast the pointer. But can this be done automatically?